# Django autocomplete a foreign key field with a previous value (Forms)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-formwizard

I use `form wizard` to create a multiple step form based on 2 models.

models.py :

```
class Author(models.Model):
    refCode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    birthDate = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)


class Book(models.Model):
    refCodeAuthor = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
```

view.py :

```
class AuthorWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [AuthorForm, DescriptionForm, BookForm] 
    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        form_values={}
        for form in form_list:
            form_values.update(form.cleaned_data)
        auth = Author(**form_values)
        auth.save()


        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_values':form_values,
        })
```

I have 3 steps, corresponding to `form_list`

[AuthorForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IagGD.png)

[DescriptionForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCB31.png)

[BookForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kpAq.png)

When I am on `BookForm`, I don't want to display `refCodeAuthor` but autocomplete this field with the value of `refCode` in the step `AuthorForm`. 
The user creates an author, then he add his books. He doesn't have to choose a `refCodeAuthor` although it isn't in the same model.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_form method in your AuthorWizard class:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super(AuthorWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
    if step is None:
        step = self.steps.current
    if step == '3':
        #and here change the field of the form:
        form.fields['refCodeAuthor'] = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1')['refCode']
```

Another solution would be to pass it through kwargs, and pop it before form initialization, although is hard to recommend anything if you do not provide the forms.py file as well